# What is the average increase of reputation of a beginning user on SO?

Tags: discussion, reputation, statistics

Is there somewhere I can look to discover a graph showing the average reputation-gain of a new user?  In my current *obsession* with rep, I need to know if my gain has been above or below average.  :)

I should say that I see lots of folks making custom queries to gather various statistics, but `$I < 0*$idea` how to do that, or if I even can with only 101 rep.

Comment: Well, when comparing reputation gained within whole week you done great in the previous week, jumping 2256 places ahead and landing as #209 in whole of SO - I'd say it's way above the average. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out the [Reputation Leagues](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/week/stackoverflow).

It shows how you are doing in relation to everyone currently rather than other new(*) users historically, but as reputation largely just measures participation, that's all you can meaningfully learn.

(*) Where "new" means those with more than 200 rep (thanks Jon).

Comment: "* users with less than 200 reputation are not tracked in the leagues" -- that makes it somewhat difficult.

Comment: @Jon - ah, that's a flaw in my answer then.

Comment: Nice one! I bet Jon Skeet is there for.. ever? :-D

Answer (score 4):

There's no rep requirement for mining the available data, and no amount of rep in the world will let you mine the non-public data. [Go for it](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new); I suspect you'll be interested in `Reputation` and `CreationDate` in the `Users` table.

Be warned that the average is likely to be a worthless number, though. Lots of people come by, post once and never participate again.